# Do characters map into $S^1$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra. Then a character is defined to be a non-trivial continuous homomorphism $A \to \mathbb C$. I'm not sure why I think this but: aren't characters really maps $A \to S^1$? I know that the operator norm of a character is $1$ so $|\tau(a)|\le 1$. But for some reason I think we have $|\tau (a)|=1$.

Comment: What about $\tau(0) = 0$?

Comment: @Crostul Yeah, I know. I don't know why I think that.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $A$ is a unital $C^\ast$-algebra, and let $U(A) = \{u \in A \mid u^\ast u = u u^\ast = 1\}$ be the group of unitaries of $A$. Suppose that $\tau : A \to \mathbb{C}$ is a $\ast$-character, so that $\tau(a^\ast) = \overline{\tau(a)}$ for all $a \in A$. What is the range of a character $\tau$ on the *algebra* $A$ when restricted to the *group* $U(A)$?

If $A$ is just a unital Banach algebra, replace $U(A)$ with $GL(A)$, the group of all invertible elements of $A$, and remember that group characters that need not correspond to unitary representations only need to take their values in $\mathbb{C}^\times$.